# Image showing up too small in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, html-email, email-attachments, email

I'm trying to setup an HTML email template and I noticed that when I send it to a BlackBerry device, it shows up too small.  The original image size is 222x9.  I know that the BlackBerry server reduces the size of embedded pictures but I was wondering if there is a way to display my image full size in the BlackBerry. I'm using a Bold 9900 with 7.1 OS.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried uploading the picture to an online server and linking the url?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't work